# C++ template param deduction is not working

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, boost-function, boost-signals2

I need to override connection between `boost::signals2::signal` and `boost::function`.
For this purpose I've created following template function:

```
template<typename T>
void bind(boost::signals2::signal<T> &signal, boost::function<T> function) {
  // override code ...
}
```

I want to make use of this `bind` as simple as it can be.
From what I've read in posts on similar issues, template parameter should be deduced from function arguments.
But in my case when there's no explicit parameter it's not working.

```
boost::signals2::signal<void ()> my_signal;

bind<void ()>(my_signal, boost::bind(&A::func, this)); // this works
bind(my_signal, boost::bind(&A::func, this));          // error: no matching function for call
```

Am I missing something?
Can there be any workaround to avoid explicit template parameter?

Comment: What is the declaration of `my_signal`?

Comment: @ildjarn Sorry, I should put it there. It is `boost::signals2::signal<void ()> my_signal;`

Comment: Template argument deduction happens before any conversion. There is no exact match in the second call. Boost::bind gives you something can be converted to your second parameter, but that can only happens after template argument deduction. Thus you need the explicit call. Or you can make the whole second parameter a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument type is not `std::function<T>`, but some bind type, so the compiler is unable to deduce the `T` for the second function parameter. You need to tell the compiler "You are OK with not finding a type for `T` in the second function parameter". This can be done by making the second parameter a non-deduced context.

```
template<typename T>
void bind(boost::signals2::signal<T> &signal, 
          typename std::common_type<boost::function<T>>::type function) {
  // override code ...
}
```